# How to fix blank screen when using react router in redux

Tags: reactjs, webpack, redux, react-router

With localhost, it's normal. But when I use "npm run build" and upload the source to server live, My page is the blank screen which doesn't have any error, warning. This is my codes. Thanks for any help.

```
    'use strict';
import React from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import { createStore , applyMiddleware  } from 'redux';

import dataService from './box-message/api';

import switchsApp from './box-message/reducers';
import App from './box-message/components';

import {Router, Route, browserHistory} from 'react-router';
import MyProfile from './profile';

import '../index.html';
import '../libs/js/socketcluster.min.js';
import '../libs/css/styles.min.css';

window.store = createStore(switchsApp , applyMiddleware(dataService));

window.store.dispatch({type: 'GET_MESSAGE_DATA'});

render(
    <Provider store={window.store} >
        <Router history={browserHistory}>
            <Route path="/" component={App} />
            <Route path="/question" component={MyProfile} />
        </Router>
    </Provider>
    ,document.getElementById('root')
)
```

Comment: Why at line 1 you have `'use trick';`? Maybe you intended [`'use strict';`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Strict_mode) instead?.

Comment: There's a decent chance to solve the problem, you need to share more about the deploy process. For example, what are you using to build the app? Some of the syntax would suggest a modern build process with babel.  Is the computer that the 'server live' is on similar to your dev environment? What are the logs that the browser gives you on the blank page?

Comment: Sorry . this is my mistake about vocabulary . I'll fix it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the way when run subfolder with react router.

```
import {Router, Route, browserHistory , hashHistory, IndexRoute , useRouterHistory  } from 'react-router';
import { createHistory } from 'history'

const appHistory = useRouterHistory(createHistory)({
  basename: "/demos/v1"
});
render(
    <Provider store={window.store}>
        <Router history={appHistory}>
            <Route path="/" component={App}>
                <IndexRoute component={BoxMessage} />
                <Route path="/profile" component={MyProfile} >
                    <Route path="/profile/:id" component={MyProfile}/>
                    <Route path="/profile/:id/:fisrt_name" component={MyProfile}/>
                    <Route path="/profile/:id/:fisrt_name/:last_name" component={MyProfile}/>
                    <Route path="/profile/:id/:fisrt_name/:last_name/:avatar" component={MyProfile}/>
                 </Route>
            </Route>
        </Router>
    </Provider> 
    ,
    document.getElementById('root')
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
<IndexRoute component={App}/>
```

Answer (score 0):

I edited something in my router. I use "browserHistory" to pretty url . **It's working so well at localhost**. I can swap router between index and profile page easily. But I meet again "blank screen" problem when upload server live (my domain is https).So i confuse with them . I need to helps . Thanks all!

. P/s : I use react-router : v3.0.2

```
import {Router, Route, browserHistory , hashHistory, IndexRoute} from 'react-router';

class App extends React.Component{

    constructor(props) {

        super(props);
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <section> 
                {this.props.children}
            </section>
        )
    }
}

render(
    <Provider store={window.store}>
        <Router history={browserHistory}>
            <Route path="/" component={App}>
                <IndexRoute component={BoxMessage} />
                <Route path="/profile" component={MyProfile} />
            </Route>
        </Router>
    </Provider> 
    ,
    document.getElementById('root')
)
```

Comment: Did you try to remove cache? because you said that you upload to remote host so that it may be a posible problem.

Comment: I removed browser's cache, but it's same that. I will try to search more. 
Thanks, ThànhChungBùi so much about your ideas.

Comment: I saw the problem. If I run the domain with "domain.net" => it worked.
But if i run "domain.net/demos/" => It wouldn't work.
I'll search the way with run with subfolder